# Add value to mySql db via JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have this function, where when a user presses a button, a accordion with content goes down. Then a user is able to add a value from a textbox into the mysql db. But, I want the hidden day value in the html form to be the value from the accordion button. The value of the button (Day) is always empty.

Im using php to add the value to the db, but the day input into the database works as long as the day input is not hidden. But I want the vale from the accordion button to be the value that is inserted in the db when the user fills in the form.

All help is appriciated!

function:

```
var showDate = new Date();
var theForm = `<form class="" action="insertIntoCalendar.php" method="post"> 
                  <input id="day"type="hidden" name="day" value=""><br>
                  <input id="formInputPwd" type="text" name="message" value="" placeholder="Message"><br>
                  <input  id="formInputPwd" type="number" name="hours" value="" placeholder="Hours"><br>
                  <input id="btnCreateUser"  type="submit" name="" value="Send">
               </form>`;

function drawTable(forDate) {
    var daysInMonth = new Date(forDate.getFullYear(),forDate.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
    var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
    var newdate = forDate.getFullYear() +"-"+ ("0"+ (forDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var calendar = document.getElementById("calendar");
    calendar.innerHTML = "";
    for (var r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
        var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        calendar.appendChild(newRow);
        for (var c = 0; c < 31 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
            var day1 = ("0" + (c + 1)).slice(-2);
            var textarea = document.createElement("button");
            textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", day1 );
            textarea.setAttribute("class", "row");
            newRow.appendChild(textarea);
            textarea.setAttribute("name", "day");
            textarea.setAttribute("id", "day");
            textarea.setAttribute("day",  newdate + "-" + day1 );
            textarea.setAttribute("value", newdate + "-" + day1);
            textarea.innerHTML = day1; 
            var textarea1 = document.createElement("div");
            textarea1.setAttribute("class", "content");
            newRow.appendChild(textarea1);
            textarea1.innerHTML = theForm;
            cellsToDraw--;
        }
    }
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var content = this.nextElementSibling;
            var active = checkIfAnyVisible();
            if (active) {
                active.className = 'content';
                active.style.maxHeight = null;
            }

            if (content.style.maxHeight){
                content.style.maxHeight = null;
                content.className = 'content';
            } else if (!checkIfAnyVisible()) {
                content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
                content.style.width = "100%";
                content.className = 'content active';
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using AJAX instead of a simple form action mechanism? Also, please be careful when inserting data into your database that the user has entered - if you're not careful you could be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @MichaelCurry I have never used Ajax, thats why I decided to use php and JS. Is there a way to do this with JS?

Comment: You can use AJAX with JS, that's why I suggested it. It's a way of calling your PHP file from JS and having the result returned to JS. You can either use jQuery to do it the easy way or if you don't want to do that, here's a tutorial on how to do it with vanilla JS along with how to do it using jQuery: https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-vanilla-ajax-without-jquery/